# Return type for stored procedure returning ints

Tags: asp.net, linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure with a simple SELECT statement:

```
SELECT UserId FROM SomeTable
```

I find that I need to create a new object in order to wrap it in LINQ.

```
[FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.MyProc")]
[ResultType(typeof(ISingleResult<TestClass>))]
public ISingleResult<TestClass> GetMyProc([Parameter(Name = "SomeId", DbType = "Int")]int someId, [Parameter(Name = "AnotherId", DbType = "Int")]int anotherId)
{
     var result = ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), someId, anotherId);
     return (ISingleResult<TestClass>)(result.ReturnValue);
}
```

Had to add this class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Column(Name = "UserId", DbType = "Int")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

This seems kind of ridiculous.  Can I avoid creating TestClass, in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I avoid creating TestClass, in this case?

Not with the framework you're currently using.

There are many other options out there. You could use ADO.NET directly; but then you're working with a `DataTable` instead of `TestClass`. You could use Dapper; where you'd still need `TestClass` but you wouldn't need `GetMyProc`. You could use a framework that *generates* the code, like an EF data model, or some other third-party framework.

But in general, the data needs marshaled into something.